# Not able to connect to Teradata using DB-Navigator(plugin)

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

When I am trying to connect to the teradata using Db-navigator getting the following error.[image]

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: I guess you should contact plugin author to get support - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator / If you are using Idea Ultimate, please read this doc to know how to connect to database using custom JDBC driver - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/other-databases.html#using-user-driver-files

Comment: @YuriWin Thanks for the information, I tried to open a new issue but they won't allow me to do that. I am not using the intellij-idea Ultimate. As I couldn't open an issue hence I had to put my question there, I already put a question on Intellij-idea forum.

Comment: this is a third-party plugin, so I would recommend to use vendor tracker https://database-navigator.atlassian.net/browse/DBNE-2779 or at least contact him via email.